# Query takes for ever on SQL server to execute

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

Following is the error message I get when I tried to execute `Select *` for the table in SQl Server, Any suggestions would be appreciated.

> "lock request time out period exceeded
>   sql server"

Comment: What if you add a `NOLOCK` query hint?

Comment: @Yuck I wouldn't recommend using `NOLOCK` as a solution without knowing more about the data he is attempting to pull. This can be dangerous if he really does need a lock on the table.

Comment: Here's a suggestion: select only the data you need.

Comment: @George: Potentially dirty, but not necessarily *dangerous*. Also without seeing **any code** it's hard to provide concrete suggestions of any form. =)

Comment: @Yuck I say dangerous in the manner that it may be dangerous to the integrity of the data he is pulling.  But yes, I agree -- not enough information to provide an accurate solution.

Comment: @Yuck and @George there is a hibernate transaction that obtained the lock while writing the data and did not release the lock it seems. when I close all the connections to database the query runs fine. I also ran sp_who2  to find whats going on

Comment: sp_lock will give the object upon which lock is acquired , this returns object id's, get the object name as follows SELECT OBJECT_NAME(012333) then get SPID of the job, I killed the job using the command kill spid then everything is back to normal.

Answer (score 1):

Look at SQL hints, in particular `WITH (NOLOCK)`

http://www.developerfusion.com/article/1688/sql-server-locks/4/

Answer (score 0):

When you do you `SELECT` you're locking the table. But your `SELECT` takes so much time, that SQL ends it, in order not to keep the table locked, mainly because SQL server thinks it's a bug.

Comment: Does SQL Server do lock escalation during or prior to results being returned?

Comment: Honestly I don't know. You'll have to ask google or people smarter than me =)